# Onmousedown does not allow me to click a link

Tags: javascript, html

I try to build a context menu on right click, and it works well, except for one thing. In my li item, I have some links (href).
But if I click on these links, the context menu doesn't follow the href, but simply closes the context menu.

I'm doing something wrong but I can't see the error:

**My actual code:**

```
 const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
  
  function showMenu(x, y) {
    menu.style.left = x + 'px';
    menu.style.top = y + 'px';
    menu.classList.add('menu-show');
  }

  function hideMenu() {
    menu.classList.remove('menu-show');
  }

  function onContextMenu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showMenu(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
  }

  function onMouseDown(e) {
    hideMenu();
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
  }

  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="https://flarum.it" class="menu-btn">
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            <span class="menu-text">Open</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/justoverclockl/pen/zYZKLNQ here the codepen if can be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking a link event occurs along with the `onmouseup` event. You are already making this process impossible with `onmousedown`.

---

All you have to do is listen for the `mouseup` event instead of the `mousedown` event and perhaps change the name of your `"onMouseDown"` function to `"onMouseUp"`.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
```

#### Example code snippet

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

function showMenu(x, y){
    menu.style.left = x + 'px';
    menu.style.top = y + 'px';
    menu.classList.add('menu-show');
}

function hideMenu(){
    menu.classList.remove('menu-show');
}

function onContextMenu(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showMenu(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
}

function onMouseUp(e){
    hideMenu();
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
}

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
```

```css
/* Page */

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 0%, #a6b9c1 100%) no-repeat;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2 {
    color: #555;
}

/* Menu */

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background: #eee;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e5e5e5 100px, #e5e5e5 100%);
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 15px) scale(.95);
    transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu-item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-btn { 
    display: block;
    color: #444;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

button.menu-btn {
    background: none;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

a.menu-btn {
    outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-text {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.menu-btn .fa {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.menu-item:hover > .menu-btn { 
    color: #fff; 
    outline: none; 
    background-color: #2E3940;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5D6D79, #2E3940);
    border: 1px solid #2E3940;
}

.menu-item-disabled {
    opacity: .5;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu-item-disabled .menu-btn {
    cursor: default;
}

.menu-separator {
    display:block;
    margin: 7px 5px;
    height:1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.menu-item-submenu::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #808080; 
}

.menu-item-submenu:hover::after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.menu .menu {
    top: 4px;
    left: 99%;
}

.menu-show,
.menu-item:hover > .menu {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-item:hover > .menu {
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="https://google.com" class="menu-btn">
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            <span class="menu-text">Open</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```